# Firestore Listen call is blocking other API resolving in EDGE browser

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, microsoft-edge

I have received a response from the other API calls, but the EDGE browser is not populating the data on the screen. Instead, it is waiting for the Firestore Listen call to end and then resolves the payload.

Comment: The Firestore Listen call takes around 35-58 seconds to resolve. Only facing this issue in EDGE and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Can you provide sample code or steps with the help of that we can produce the issue to make a test with Edge?